# How to change php.ini on iPage shared host

Tags: php, configuration, ini, shared-hosting, php-ini

I'm using IPage shared hosting. 
I want to change the max upload file size for example.
I want to put these values in the ini file

```
post_max_size = 30M
upload_max_filesize = 100M
max_execution_time = 900
memory_limit = 100M
```

I can't find php.ini to change those php configurations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a long time, I found the place of that PHP ini on the IPage shared hosting

Control Panel>>Scripting and Add-Ons>>CGI and Scripted Language Support>>PHP Scripting

search for

```
post_max_size =
upload_max_filesize =
max_execution_time =
memory_limit =
```

Then replace them with

```
post_max_size = 30M
upload_max_filesize = 100M
max_execution_time = 900
memory_limit = 100M
```

Then press save.